# Connecting to localhost via system IP address

Tags: linux-mint, ip, webserver

I am using Linux Mint 15, and I am running a Ruby web server(Thin) on port 3000.

I can connect from my machine via `localhost:3000`, but the moment I type in the system IP address (eg. `http://192.168.43.250:3000`) (that I get from `ifconfig`), then I get a 'Webpage not available' message.

I would like to connect to my web server via a tablet over a wi-fi connection for testing purposes so I need to be able to connect via the system IP address.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does the command `iptables-save` show you something? If could be a `INPUT` rule of your firewall that is dropping/rejecting packets on your network interface.

Comment: Can you ping that address from any (other) machine?

Comment: Is your web server listening on that IP?

Comment: Type: `netstat -putan | grep :80` to see if your webserver is listening on this ip address or just on the loopback ip.

Comment: @nwilder ```iptables-save``` shows nothing

Comment: @JosephR. don't have another machine available :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually caused by 2 things.

#### 1. Firewall

The firewall may be blocking packets from getting to your web server. To confirm you can temporarily disable it.

```
$ sudo ufw disable
```

Then try accessing the server again, `http://192.168.43.230:3000`. If that works then you can add an exception to the firewall to allow this port through. First re-enable it.

```
$ sudo ufw enable
```

Then allow traffic to that port.

```
$ sudo ufw allow 3000
```

#### 2. Not binding to port

Each interface and therefore each IP address that your computer has, each have ports associated to it. So your localhost IP address (127.0.0.1) as well as any other IPs (192.168.43.250) each have ports. You can bind to port 3000 for all interfaces (IPs) by often specifying your IP as 0.0.0.0. But in your case you can also just bind to 192.168.43.250.

To start `thin` you should only need to do this to get it to bind to port 0.0.0.0:

```
$ sudo thin start -p 3000
```

Comment: Not binding to port was the problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> I get a 'Webpage not available' message.

If you are using chrome and you click the "More" button and see at bottom:

```
Error code: ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
```

Then it's because of you firewall.  If you are using iptables, you need to add a rule like:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

`3000` is the port number in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

sudo ufw reset

If, for whatever reason, you need to reset your cloud server’s rules to their default settings, you can do this by typing this command:

Refer below link:
[How To Setup a Firewall with UFW on an Ubuntu and Debian Cloud Server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-an-ubuntu-and-debian-cloud-server)